# SQL Server 2016 Agent jobs start, but hang indefinitely on first run after a server bounce

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have multiple SQL Server Agent jobs that hang indefinitely upon first run after the server bounces. The jobs execute as scheduled, but never perform any action and stay in "Executing" status indefinitely. Rebooting the Agent from the SQL Server Configuration GUI resolves the issue.

NOTES:

- Neither the Engine logs nor the Agent logs seem to show anything of value.
- I have tried setting the Agent Service to "delayed start" in Windows Services.
- The Agent is currently using an MSA.

Comment: All jobs or just some? What step types do the frozen jobs use? Can you see any open connections from the job step, and what are they doing if so?

Comment: I had been thinking it was all jobs, but now it looks like it may only be the jobs that have "Operating System (CmdExec)" type steps.

Comment: What is your exact version of SQL? Do you have the service packs and cumulative updates?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 13.0.5026.0